# Poisson brackets and magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, poisson-brackets

I'm a maths student trying to teach myself some physics so sorry if I'm missing something simple here. I think the main problem is lack of experience with the Levi-Cevita symbol.

We have a particle in a magnetic field $\mathbf{B}=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}$, described by the Hamiltonian (taking $c=1$):

\begin{equation*}
 H=\frac{1}{2m}(p-eA(\mathbf{r}))^2=\frac{m}{2}\mathbf{\dot{r}}^2
 \end{equation*}

I am told that the Poisson bracket structure reads $\{m\dot{r}_a,m\dot{r}_b\}=e\epsilon_{abc}B_c$, and have tried to prove this as follows:

\begin{equation*}
\left\lbrace m \, \dot{r}_a, m \, \dot{r}_b \right\rbrace = \left\lbrace p_a - e \, A_a(\mathbf{r}), p_b - e \, A_b(\mathbf{r}) \right\rbrace \\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~= \left\lbrace p_a, p_b \right\rbrace - e \, \left\lbrace p_a, A_b(\mathbf{r})\right\rbrace + e \, \left\lbrace p_b, A_a(\mathbf{r}) \right\rbrace + e^2 \, \left\lbrace A_a(\mathbf{r}), A_b(\mathbf{r}) \right\rbrace
\end{equation*}

Now the first and last terms in here are zero, and so this simplifies to:

\begin{equation*}
\left\lbrace m \, \dot{r}_a, m \, \dot{r}_b \right\rbrace = e\frac{\partial{A_b(\mathbf{r})}}{\partial{r_a}} - e\frac{\partial{A_a(\mathbf{r})}}{\partial{r_b}}
\end{equation*}

using the fact that $\left\lbrace p_a, f(\mathbf{r}) \right\rbrace = -\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{r})}{\partial r_a}$. I'm not too sure where to go from here, I'm guessing there is some sort of manipulation with the Levi-Civita symbol needed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can someone elaborate on why this is off-topic? @jl2 "ask[ed] about a specific physics concept" and "show[ed] some effort to work through the problem," no? I think he got 90% of the way there and just needed some pointers on the Levi-Cevita symbol, like he said. I guess I could have  stopped a few steps short in my answer, letting him finish it? Even still, that would be regarding my answer, not his question.

Comment: Sorry really confused by this. I don't see how the question isn't specific, or how I haven't shown any effort to reach a solution? Is there any way I can get the answer back? Nothing in the Help Centre seems to indicate there's anything wrong with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to use [Einstein summation notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) throughout.

You're almost there. You just need to use
$$
{\bf B} = \nabla \times {\bf A}
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
B_k &=& \frac{\partial}{\partial r_i} A_j \epsilon_{i j k} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r_i} A_j \epsilon_{i j k} + \frac{\partial}{\partial r_j} A_i \epsilon_{j i k}\right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r_i} A_j - \frac{\partial}{\partial r_j} A_i \right) \epsilon_{i j k}\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
There I used the antisymmetry of $\epsilon_{i j k}$ under exchange of any two indices.

Now using the first equation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Three_dimensions_2),
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
B_k \epsilon_{k r s} &=& \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r_i} A_j - \frac{\partial}{\partial r_j} A_i \right) \epsilon_{k i j} \epsilon_{k r s} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r_i} A_j - \frac{\partial}{\partial r_j} A_i \right) \left(\delta_{i r} \delta_{j s} - \delta_{i s} \delta_{j r}\right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r_r} A_s - \frac{\partial}{\partial r_s} A_r \right) - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r_s} A_r - \frac{\partial}{\partial r_r} A_s \right) \\
&=& \frac{\partial}{\partial r_r} A_s - \frac{\partial}{\partial r_s} A_r
\end{eqnarray}
$$